# Linear transformation of triangular random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, linear-transformations

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with densities $f_X (x)$ and $f_Y (y)$. Prove that for $Y = aX + b$, $a\neq 0$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$
>   $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{|a|} f_X\left ( \frac{y-b}{a} \right )$$

I need to do that for two cases $a> 0$ and $a <0$.

> Sketch $f_X (x) = \operatorname{tri} (x)$
>   and $f_Y (y)$ for $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. How do the parameters $a$ and $b$ affect the transformed density?

If $a>0$ then $F_Y(y)=P\left (aX+b\leq  y\right )=P\left (X\leq\frac{y-b}{a}  \right )=F_X\left (\frac{y-b}{a}  \right )$

If $a<0$ then $F_Y(y)=P\left (aX+b\leq  y\right )=P\left (X\geq\frac{y-b}{a}  \right ) =1-P\left (X<\frac{y-b}{a}  \right )=1-F_X\left (\frac{y-b}{a}  \right) +P\left (X=\frac{y-b}{a}  \right )$

How do I get this $\frac{1}{|a|} f_x\left( \frac{y-b}{a} \right)$? I have $F_X$. $f_y(y)=F_Y'(y)$?

How do I sketch the [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) $f_X (x) = \operatorname{tri} (x)$
and $f_Y (y)$ for $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. How do the parameters $a$ and $b$ affect the transformed density?

Answer (score 2):

To get $\frac{1}{a}$ term, just use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy} F_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)=\frac 1 a f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)$$

$b$ shifts $y$ by a constant amount. $a$ scales $y-b$ and the $1/a$ ensures the PDF integrates to 1.

Comment: What about the rest od my questions? (Asking this so I can accept your answer)

Comment: @Alena can you specify what the tri function is?

Comment: triangle @qwr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $P\left(X = \frac{y-b}{a}\right)$ is zero since $X$ is a continuous random variable. Secondly, differentiating $y\mapsto F_Y(y)$, one has
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\text d}{\text d y} F_Y(y) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
\phantom{-} \frac{1}{a} f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)\quad &\text{if } a>0 \\
-\frac{1}{a} f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)\quad &\text{if } a<0 
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Therefore, $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{|a|} f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)$.

If $a=2$, then $1/|a|$ divides the amplitude of the probability density function (PDF) $f_X$ by two, and $y/a$ dilates the PDF by a factor two along the abscissas (so that the integral of the PDF is kept equal to one). Moreover, if $b=3$, the $-b/a$ translates the PDF to the right by three units along the abscissas. In the case of the [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) distribution $f_X(x) = \text{tri}(x)$, we obtain the following graph of PDFs:

[image: plot]

Comment: Why is that zero?

Comment: How do the parameters a and b affect the the transformed density?